# Prove sets have equal cardinality: $(0, 1)$ and $(3, 8)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I managed to prove one-to-one by defining $f(x) = x + 1$.
I'm not sure how to prove it's surjective. I know I need to prove $f(x) = y$, meaning $y = x + 1$, but don't know how to go from here.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $f(x)=x+1$ maps $(0,1)\subseteq \mathbb R$ to $(1,2)\subseteq \mathbb R$.  What about $5x+3$?

Comment: 5 + 3 works for one-to-one too

Comment: This has been answered already, but I feel useful to point out the following: draw the intervals as sides of a rectangle. Then draw the diagonal. That's your bijection.

Answer (score 2):

$g(x)=5x+3$ is a bijection from $(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R$ to $(3,8)\subseteq\mathbb R$.

It is surjective (onto), because, if $3<y<8,$ then $x=(y-3)/5$ maps to $y$ and $0<x<1$,

and it is injective (one-to-one), because, if $5x_1+3=5x_2+3$, then $x_1=x_2$.

On the other hand $f(x)=x+1$ maps $(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R$ to $(1,2)\subseteq\mathbb R$, not into $(3,8)\subseteq \mathbb R.$

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In general, for any interval $(a,b)$, we can construct a bijection to $\mathbb{R}$. An (admittedly crude) example of one might be $$f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{2x-b-a}{b-a}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2} \right).$$ So, for the particular example, if we take a bijection $f_1$ between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$, and we then take a bijection $f_2$ between $(3,8)$ and $\mathbb{R}$, $$f_1\circ f_2^{-1}$$ will be a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(3,8)$.